# progress bar to run automatically when page refresh (automatically)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting new data from database every one minute. Displaying data on a web page. Data updating will start when user presses a START button. Then the page will automatically update every minute. I would like to add a progress bar showing time. (it should start when the user press the START button. I managed it. But as the page refreshes automatically, it should run the progress bar after automatic page refresh as well. How to do this? any suggestions please.

```
<body>
   <div id="progressBar">
   <div></div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear').html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
  if(timeleft > 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
      }, 1000);
  }
};
  </script>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#MyButton').click(function(){
         progress(60, 60, $('#progressBar'));
      });
    });
  </script>


  <input type="button" value="START" id="MyButton" >


  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessionStorage` to store the time left variable as it is stored on the user's browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

```
function progress(...) {
   .
   .
   sessionStorage.setItem('timeleft', timeleft);
   .
 }

 function checkAutoStart() {
    var timeleft = sessionStorage.getItem('timeleft');
    if(timeleft && timeleft > 0) {
        progress(timeleft, 60, $('#progressBar'));
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
    .
    .
    checkAutoStart();
 }
```